# Perform math using elements from lists of lists with different lengths in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two (Lists of Lists) of different lengths **(data_List, dataTwo_List)** and I want to call the **"funcX"** function in a loop that iterates through both lists at the same time without producing the *"List Out of Index"* error using the size of **data_List**.

```
def funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-y1)**2 + (x2-y2)**2)

data_List = [[3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 7], [5, 1], [5, 5], [7, 3], [7, 5], [8, 5]]
dataTwo_List = [[5, 5], [3, 6], [7, 3]]

funcX(data_List[0][0],dataTwo_List[0][0],data_List[0][1],dataTwo_List[0][1])
funcX(data_List[1][0],dataTwo_List[0][0],data_List[1][1],dataTwo_List[0][1])
funcX(data_List[2][0],dataTwo_List[0][0],data_List[2][1],dataTwo_List[0][1])
funcX(data_List[3][0],dataTwo_List[0][0],data_List[3][1],dataTwo_List[0][1])
...
...
funcX(data_List[0][0],dataTwo_List[1][0],data_List[0][1],dataTwo_List[1][1])
funcX(data_List[1][0],dataTwo_List[1][0],data_List[1][1],dataTwo_List[1][1])
funcX(data_List[2][0],dataTwo_List[1][0],data_List[2][1],dataTwo_List[1][1])
funcX(data_List[3][0],dataTwo_List[1][0],data_List[3][1],dataTwo_List[1][1])
...
...
```

Comment: To clarify, this should do for all `(x1, y1)` in `data_List`, and all `(x2, y2)` in `dataTwo_List`? Have you tried using a double for-loop?

Comment: Yes, all (x1, y1) of data_List and all (x2, y2) in dataTwo_List.
I tried a double for-loop, but a "List out of Index" error occured.

Comment: Please add the double for-loop you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `itertools`:

```
import math

def funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)

data_List = [[3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 7], [5, 1], [5, 5], [7, 3], [7, 5], [8, 5]]
dataTwo_List = [[5, 5], [3, 6], [7, 3]]

i = 0
stop = len(dataTwo_List)
while i < stop:
  for list1 in data_List:
    funcX(list1[0], dataTwo_List[i][0], list1[1], dataTwo_List[i][1])
  i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two alternatives:

1. `zip(*iterables)` function. Returns a zip object, which is an iterator of tuples where the first item in each passed iterator is paired together. If the passed iterators have different lengths, the iterator with the least items decides the length of the new iterator.
2. `itertools.zip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=None)` function. Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue.

Whatever the choice, the result is similar to:

```py
import math

def funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)

data_List = [[3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 7], [5, 1], [5, 5], [7, 3], [7, 5], [8, 5]]
dataTwo_List = [[5, 5], [3, 6], [7, 3]]

for ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) in zip(data_List, dataTwo_List):
    funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

**Update.**
I'm sorry, I did not finish seeing the result you wanted to obtain, I think this is what you wanted to get:

```py
import math 
from itertools import product


def funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)


data_List = [[3, 4], [3, 6], [3, 8], [4, 5], [4, 7], [5, 1], [5, 5], [7, 3], [7, 5], [8, 5]]
dataTwo_List = [[5, 5], [3, 6], [7, 3]]


for ((x2, y2), (x1, y1)) in product(dataTwo_List, data_List):
    funcX(x1, x2, y1, y2)
```

The `product` function return a iterator that generate the cartesian product between the two lists of elements. I put the dataTwo_List first to generate the same order that you want.

Comment: This won't work because it will only do the first `len(dataTwo_List)` elements of `data_List`.

Comment: Right, you are right, I did not finish seeing the solution that he hoped to obtain. I already added the update